# Date column for Date of Birth

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a date & time field that I am using to capture users 'date of birth' but the control on the edit form is not geared towards going back 30 years. The user is forced to click the arrows multiple times to cycle the months and then years. How can I make this quicker and easier?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to have them just type their birthdate in rather than using the date picker style input.

Answer (score 0):

As I wanted to make this as easy as possible for the end user and also wanted continuity amongst the entered values I created 4 additional columns. DOB day, DOB Month, DOB Year & Date of Birth. The first 3 columns were drop downs containing 1- 31 days, JAN - DEC etc. A created a workflow that then moves this data into the Date of Birth column in the format I wanted. The first 3 columns were then hidden from all of the forms and views. The NEW from was then formatted to accommodate the 3 drop down controls by entering a 3 column table